# Nuget restore error in azure devop server: NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

What could be the reason for getting this error when I do Nuget restore in Azure devops. I don't get it in visual studio 2019

```
NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Common.Logs': Common.Logs (>= 0.8.0) (via package/Common.Drivers 0.8.1), Common.Logs (>= 0.8.0) (via project/Common.Drivers 0.8.1)
```

I fail to see how they are in conflict both `package/Common.Drivers 0.8.1` and `project/Common.Drivers 0.8.1` are referencing the same dependency of `Common.Logs (>= 0.8.0)`

I am using Nuget 5.5.1

Ymal equivalent is

```
steps:
- task: NuGetRestore@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    selectOrConfig: config
    nugetConfigPath: ./nuget.config
    noCache: true
```

#### UPDATE

The log is as follows, please note, the problem is coming in most of the projects, since I am actively try to solve the below log is different and error is coming for a different project. I had to slim down the logs, as there is char limit in SO, but the error details are there.

```
##[section]Starting: NuGet restore
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet
Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Azure Artifacts and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.
Version      : 2.153.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget
==============================================================================
[command]C:\WINDOWS\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Detected NuGet version 5.5.1.6542 / 5.5.1+fd2f920875c33464efb4b5ac366d8b8a83239dc0.fd2f920875c33464efb4b5ac366d8b8a83239dc0
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
[command]C:\agent\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.5.1\x64\nuget.exe restore C:\agent\_work\3\s\Senna.sln -NoCache -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile C:\agent\_work\3\s\nuget.config
NuGet Version: 5.5.1.6542
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.5.0.12403' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 204000
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\xaz5zuow.yet.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\1zcgcoou.qpv.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreUseCustomAfterTargets="True" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="C:\agent\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.5.1\x64\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="C:\agent\_work\3\s\\" /p:RestoreConfigFile="C:\agent\_work\3\s\nuget.config" /p:SolutionDir="C:\agent\_work\3\s\\" /p:SolutionName="Senna"

Checking compatibility for Company.TestRunners 0.8.14 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Logs 0.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Data 0.8.11 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Reactive 4.3.2 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Methods 0.8.6 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.3 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Exceptions 0.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Measurables 0.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.2 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
All packages and projects are compatible with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Resolving conflicts for .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1...
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Module\obj\Company.Module.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Module\obj\Company.Module.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing assets file to disk. Path: C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Module\obj\project.assets.json
Writing cache file to disk. Path: C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Module\obj\project.nuget.cache
Restore completed in 72.91 ms for C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Module\Company.Module.csproj.
Reading project file C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Common.Methods.Tests\Company.Common.Methods.Tests.csproj.
Persisting no-op dg to C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Common.Methods.Tests\obj\Company.Common.Methods.Tests.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
Restoring packages for C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Common.Methods.Tests\Company.Common.Methods.Tests.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1...
Resolving conflicts for .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1...
Checking compatibility of packages on .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Logs.Serilog 0.8.2 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.2.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for NETStandard.Library 2.0.3 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Drivers 0.8.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Logs 0.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Measurables 0.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Methods 0.8.6 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Serilog 2.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Serilog.Enrichers.Thread 3.0.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Serilog.Settings.Configuration 3.0.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.2.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.2.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Exceptions 0.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Collections.NonGeneric 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.0.4 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.0.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.2.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.2.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Globalization 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.Extensions 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Threading 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.0.4 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.0.11 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Linq 4.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.0.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.0.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.2.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 2.2.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.2.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Threading.Tasks 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.AppContext 4.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Collections 4.0.11 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection.TypeExtensions 4.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Linq.Expressions 4.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.ObjectModel 4.0.12 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection.Emit 4.0.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.0.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Memory 4.5.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.IO 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection.Primitives 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for runtime.native.System 4.0.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight 4.0.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Reflection.Extensions 4.0.1 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Buffers 4.4.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Numerics.Vectors 4.4.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Text.Encoding 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
All packages and projects are compatible with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Logs.Serilog\obj\Company.Logs.Serilog.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Logs.Serilog\obj\Company.Logs.Serilog.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing assets file to disk. Path: C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Logs.Serilog\obj\project.assets.json
Writing cache file to disk. Path: C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Logs.Serilog\obj\project.nuget.cache
Restore completed in 428.54 ms for C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.Logs.Serilog\Company.Logs.Serilog.csproj.
Reading project file C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.TestRunners\Company.TestRunners.csproj.
Persisting no-op dg to C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.TestRunners\obj\Company.TestRunners.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
Restoring packages for C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.TestRunners\Company.TestRunners.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETStandard,Version=v2.0...
Resolving conflicts for .NETStandard,Version=v2.0...
Checking compatibility of packages on .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.TestRunners 0.8.14 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for NETStandard.Library 2.0.3 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Data 0.8.11 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Reactive 4.3.2 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Methods 0.8.6 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.3 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Exceptions 0.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Logs 0.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Company.Common.Measurables 0.8.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime 4.3.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.2 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Checking compatibility for Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.1.0 with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
All packages and projects are compatible with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Committing restore...
Generating MSBuild file C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.TestRunners\obj\Company.TestRunners.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.TestRunners\obj\Company.TestRunners.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing assets file to disk. Path: C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.TestRunners\obj\project.assets.json
Writing cache file to disk. Path: C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.TestRunners\obj\project.nuget.cache
Restore completed in 5.98 ms for C:\agent\_work\3\s\src\Company.TestRunners\Company.TestRunners.csproj.
Reading project file C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Repository.Msp.Tests\Company.Repository.Msp.Tests.csproj.
Persisting no-op dg to C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Repository.Msp.Tests\obj\Company.Repository.Msp.Tests.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
Restoring packages for C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Repository.Msp.Tests\Company.Repository.Msp.Tests.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.servicemodel.duplex/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.servicemodel.security/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.servicemodel.http/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.servicemodel.nettcp/index.json

....

Checking compatibility for runtime.native.System.Net.Http 4.3.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.
NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Company.Common.Exceptions': Company.Common.Exceptions (>= 0.8.0) (via package/Company.Common.Drivers 0.8.1), Company.Common.Exceptions (>= 0.8.0) (via project/Company.Common.Drivers 0.8.1) Framework: (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Company.Common.Logs': Company.Common.Logs (>= 0.8.0) (via package/Company.Common.Drivers 0.8.1), Company.Common.Logs (>= 0.8.0) (via project/Company.Common.Drivers 0.8.1) Framework: (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
An item with the same key has already been added.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at NuGet.Commands.LockFileBuilder.CreateLockFile(LockFile previousLockFile, PackageSpec project, IEnumerable`1 targetGraphs, IReadOnlyList`1 localRepositories, RemoteWalkContext context)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<ExecuteAndCommitAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<CompleteTaskAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<RunAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<RunAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)


...

Generating MSBuild file C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Measurables.Tests\obj\Company.Measurables.Tests.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing assets file to disk. Path: C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Measurables.Tests\obj\project.assets.json
Writing cache file to disk. Path: C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Measurables.Tests\obj\project.nuget.cache
Restore completed in 382.84 ms for C:\agent\_work\3\s\tests\Company.Measurables.Tests\Company.Measurables.Tests.csproj.
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/coverlet.collector/index.json 254ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.servicemodel.security/index.json 745ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/coverlet.collector/1.2.1/coverlet.collector.1.2.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/coverlet.collector/1.2.1/coverlet.collector.1.2.1.nupkg 18ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.servicemodel.http/index.json 799ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.servicemodel.duplex/index.json 811ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.servicemodel.nettcp/index.json 842ms
Resolving conflicts for .NETStandard,Version=v2.0...
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Company.Common.Exceptions': Company.Common.Exceptions (>= 0.8.0) (via package/Company.Common.Drivers 0.8.1), Company.Common.Exceptions (>= 0.8.0) (via project/Company.Common.Drivers 0.8.1) Framework: (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
NU1106: Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Company.Common.Logs': Company.Common.Logs (>= 0.8.0) (via package/Company.Common.Drivers 0.8.1), Company.Common.Logs (>= 0.8.0) (via project/Company.Common.Drivers 0.8.1) Framework: (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
An item with the same key has already been added.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at NuGet.Commands.LockFileBuilder.CreateLockFile(LockFile previousLockFile, PackageSpec project, IEnumerable`1 targetGraphs, IReadOnlyList`1 localRepositories, RemoteWalkContext context)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<ExecuteAndCommitAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<CompleteTaskAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<RunAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<RunAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args))
##[error]Packages failed to
```

Comment: Try to check the Nuget version used by VS2019. Then use “NuGet tool installer” task to install the same version of the NuGet tool.
On the other, you may set the variable: system.debug=true and share the debug log here. Please help us clarify whether "Project" and "Package" are two Projects.

Comment: `Project` is a project reference and `Package` is the package reference added using nuget. The Nuget version VS 2019 is also 5.5.1. I will try to set system.debug = true and report back.

Comment: According to the log, the "package/Company.Common.Drivers" and the "project/Company.Common.Drivers" both reference  the same package: Company.Common.xxx . And the packages only have a specific version(0.8.0). Please check the version of the dependency package.If you remove the package or project reference, will this issue be improved?